# Table does not show correctly in R using TeX

Tags: r, latex

I am trying to plot a table in R but it just print the text in a dummy format, not sure how to fix it.

My Code:

```
tex2=TeX('
     \\begin{table}[]
\\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
     \\hline
     a&b  \\\\ \\hline
    c & d \\\\ \\hline
     \\end{tabular}
     \\end{table}
     ')
plot(tex2, cex=1)
```

tex2 is equivalent of

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
 a&b  \\ \hline
 c&d  \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

as suggested by https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html

Comment: I don't think `latex2exp` supports things like tables. It looks like it mostly just supports math symbols. You may have to look elsewhere to see if there are any packages that can produce a plot from TeX code, I don't know that I've heard of one.

Comment: Thanks, I have the same feeling, Lots of packages for converting R to Latex, but seems this is the only one for Latex to R. I was thinking of writing a function which utilizes \n, |, and indent for building a simple table, which I will do in the next few days, but always its nice to see if there is an easier and more efficient tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view a LaTeX snippet in the RStudio viewer pane, with the possibility to export it as an image, you need the `texPreview` package.

```
library(texPreview)

tex <- '
\\begin{table}[]
\\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\\hline
a & b  \\\\ \\hline
c & d \\\\ \\hline
\\end{tabular}
\\end{table}
'

tex_preview(tex, imgFormat = "svg")
```

[image]

When I tried it the first time, it didn't work. I got this error:

> Error in magick_image_readpath(enc2native(path), density, depth,
>   strip) :    rsession: not authorized `/tmp/RtmpKZqeBQ/tex_tempDoc.pdf'
>   @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412

I'm using Ubuntu. I had to make a change in the file **/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml**; namely I replaced the line

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
```

with

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="PDF" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephane, just saw your response now, not sure why I have not received a an alert, I will test it and will get back to you, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thanks for the policy edit tip! I was banging my head trying to solve that error for an hour before finding this.